# I was trying to add some data to firebase firestore but it kept on replying with error loading document

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore error

[image: 1]

Here is part of the code that i have used

```
private void registerUser(String textFullName, String textEmail, String textDoB, String textGender, String textMoblie, String textPwd) {
       
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
       
FirebaseFirestore fstore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();       
 
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(textEmail, textPwd).addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()  {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
     if (task.isSuccessful()){

         FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
         DocumentReference df = fstore.collection("Users").document(firebaseUser.getUid());
         Map<String,Object> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
         userInfo.put("FullName",editTextRegisterFullName.getText().toString());
         userInfo.put("UserEmail",editTextRegisterEmail.getText().toString());
         userInfo.put("PhoneNumber",editTextRegisterMoblie.getText().toString());
         // Specify if the user is admin
         userInfo.put("isUser, "1");
         df.set(userInfo);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the document still exists?

Comment: Yes it exists but it seems there is a problem while loading it